# Plot a bar graph for pandas with x-axis using a given column

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart

I want to plot a bar chart for the following pandas data frame on Jupyter Notebook.

```
      | Month | number
-------------------------
    0 | Apr   |  6.5
    1 | May   |  7.3
    2 | Jun   |  3.9
    3 | Jul   |  5.1
    4 | Aug   |  4.1
```

I did:

```
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
trend_df.plot(kind='bar')
```

How do I make sure x-axis is actually showing month here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply specify `x` and `y` in your call to `plot` to get the bar plot you want.

```
trend_df.plot(x='Month', y='number', kind='bar')
```

[image]

Given `trend_df` as

```
In [20]: trend_df
Out[20]: 
  Month  number
0   Apr     6.5
1   May     7.3
2   Jun     3.9
3   Jul     5.1
4   Aug     4.1
```

---

This can also be accomplished by setting the column for the x-axis, as the index.

```py
# sample data
speed = [17.5, 40, 48, 52, 69, 88]
lifespan = [8, 70, 1.5, 25, 12, 28]
animal = ['pig', 'elephant', 'rabbit', 'giraffe', 'coyote', 'horse']
df = pd.DataFrame({'speed': speed, 'lifespan': lifespan, 'animal': animal})

# set the index
df.set_index('animal', inplace=True)
```

Plot all other columns as bars

```py
ax = df.plot(kind='bar', rot=0)
```

Plot specific columns as bars

```py
ax = df.plot(kind='bar', y=['speed', 'lifespan'], rot=0)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
store the data in a csv file.

example i named my file plot.csv

    save data in following format in plot.csv

Month,number

Apr,6.5

May,7.3

Jun,3.9

Jul,5.1

Aug,4.1


import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

import csv

#first read the data
data = pd.read_csv('plot.csv',sep=',')

print(data)
#create  a data frame
df = data.ix[-5:,['Month','number']]
#plot
df.plot(kind = 'bar')

plt.show()
#for ggplot
plt.style.use('ggplot')

df.plot()

plt.show()
```

Comment: In the above answer do not give line break in data

Comment: This should be deleted, it does not do what is asked in the OP, which is to specify which column is used as the x-axis.